# Need to obtain standard output size from Android camera pics

Tags: java, android, bitmap

I am working on a photobooth type app for iPhone and Android.  On iPhone, I know the exact resolution of the front camera, and am able to always output 4 mini pics predictably and make a photostrip from them.  But for Android, I need a way to resize 4 images I have taken to a width of 48px and height of 320px per image.  This way, I can build the same size photostrip I built for the iPhone version, and easily display the photostrips in a consistent manner on a website (I don't want the size of them to vary depending on platform).  On Android, how can I resize to that resolution (48x320), even if the Android camera doesn't output that aspect ratio?  Basically, I'd like to resize on Android, and have it automatically zoom as necessary until 48x320 is reached and it doesn't look stretched/distorted...I'm ok with part of the image (like the outside border) being lost in favor of getting a 48x320 image. Maybe this is just a straight Java question...

Thanks so much!